# Base.Actions.PressSave() not working on Attributes with mass actions

Tags: acumatica

I created a custom Action on Contracts that updates the description as well as attributes.

It works fine when doing a single entry and pressing the action button but during Mass Action only the description is updated and saved the attributes are not.

What do I need to do to make the Attributes values save correctly during Mass Action?

```
        public PXSelect<CSAnswers,
                 Where<CSAnswers.refNoteID, Equal<Current<Contract.noteID>>>> CSAttr;

        protected IEnumerable testAction(PXAdapter adapter)
        {
            //get the activation parameters
            var a = CSAttr.Select();
            Contract mycontract = Base.CurrentContract.Select();
            foreach (CSAnswers item in a.ToList())
            {                    
                if (item.AttributeID == "ACTA") 
                {
                    item.Value = "Won't Update1";
                    CSAttr.Update(item); //shouldn't this update?
                }
                else if (item.AttributeID == "ACTB") //desired mode set by user
                {
                    item.Value = "Won't Update2";
                    CSAttr.Update(item); //shouldn't this update?
                }
            }
            mycontract.Description = "This Works Fine";
            Base.CurrentContract.Update(mycontract);
            Base.Actions.PressSave();

            return adapter.Get();
        }
```

Comment: @AcumaticGuy, can you please share implementation of your Mass Action?

Comment: Mass action is generated from generic inquiry using tables PX.Objects.CS.Answers Left Join PX.Objects.CT.Contract on noteId=refNoteID.  Entry point is Finance\Accounts Receivable\Work Area\Manage\Customer Contracts.  Then enabled with "Enable Mass Actions on Records".  On Mass Actions tab, I add my action "testAction".  The action works fine and updates attributes on single Customer Contracts.  My question is there something different I need to do to update the attributes vs description fields?

Comment: I would suggest changing your code like this:   foreach(CSAnswers item in CSAttr.Select(this))

Comment: I tried foreach(CSAnswers item in CSAttr.Select(this)) but same result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to declare custom CSAttr data view: ContractMaint already contains Answers data view to work with Attributes.

TestAction implemented as below, successfully updates both Contract Description and Attribute Value on a brand new 6.00.1596 Acumatica ERP instance when launched from GI set up as entry-point list:

```
public class ContractMaintExt : PXGraphExtension<ContractMaint>
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        TestAction.IsMass = true;
    }

    public PXAction<Contract> TestAction;
    [PXButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Test Action")]
    public void testAction()
    {
        Contract mycontract = Base.CurrentContract.Select();
        foreach (CSAnswers attr in Base.Answers.Select())
        {
            if (attr.AttributeID == "CONFIGURAB")
            {
                attr.Value = "Updated";
                Base.Answers.Update(attr); //shouldn't this update?
            }
        }
        mycontract.Description = "This Works Fine";
        Base.Contracts.Update(mycontract);
        Base.Actions.PressSave();
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]